# Select From List selects item but does not commit change

Tags: drop-down-menu, robotframework

Using Robot Framework, I have a dropdown with multiple options.  When I use the `select from list` option I can see the selection become highlighted, but when the dropdown closes, the value is not changed.

Here is a sample of  my code:

```
click element  id=month
select from list  xpath=//select/@name="month"  September
click button  css=button.submit
```

I have tried variants of this with the `select from list by label` and `select from list by value`, and they fail with error stating the selected list or value does not exist.

Select from list by value example:

```
click element  id=month
select from list by value  xpath=//select/@name="month"  September
click button  css=button.submit
```

Select from list by label example 1:

```
click element  id=month
select from list by label  xpath=//select/@name="month"  September
click button  css=button.submit
```

Select from list by label example 2:

```
click element  id=month
select from list by label  xpath=//select/@name="month"  label=September
click button  css=button.submit
```

Anyone experienced this before where an item gets "selected" but the value does not get changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following keyword.

Pass locator as 1st argument and value as another argument

```
Select from list by label and validate
    [Arguments]    ${locator}      ${select value}
    Focus   ${locator}
    # Select from list by label 
    Select From List By Label   ${locator}  ${select value}
    # Get selected value and validate it against passed value as argument
    ${value} =  Get Selected List Label ${locator}
    Should be equal ${select value} ${value}
```

Comment: Thanks Akash!  I will give that a try!

Comment: If still there is any issue, let me know

Comment: The only change I made was that my system didn't recognize the // characters as a comment indicator.  I used the # character and it works beautifully.  Thanks again!