# Select X-Path which has contains words of another X-Path

Tags: python, xpath, robotframework

I'm having trouble when using selenium libary on ROBOT FRAMEWORK, please help.

I have a drop down menu, which has 2 elements - 1 is "Resource" and 2 is "Resource Management".
I use this keyword:

> Click element | //*/div[(contains(@class,"combo-list") or contains(@class,"dropdown"))]/descendant::*[.="Resource"]

But somehow, it only click on the Resource Management instead of Resource.
Please support. T_T

Comment: Share exact `HTML` code for the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't `Click` the element when selecting drop down list. you use the keyword `Select From List By Label`. Below is an example in your case:

```
Select From List By Label    Xpath=ChangeMe    Resource
```

This will select the entry `Resource` inside the drop down menu you locate - using the locator of your choice.

There are many different `Select From List` Keywords, which can be found on the [Selenium2Library Documentation](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Select%20From%20List).

EDIT:

Noticing another Issue: If you want to select the 2nd occurrence of an Xpath - you just encapsulate it in parentheses `()`, add the `Xpath=` prefix and at the end add the occurrence number of the Xpath. For example:

```
Xpath=(//span[contains(string(), 'Submit')])[2]
```

This finds the 2nd span which contains the word `Submit`. Meaning in my case, it finds the 2nd submit button. Even though there are 5 on the current page (In my case). [This should help you](http://ricostacruz.com/cheatsheets/xpath.html) understand Xpaths. It helped me a lot when I was learning!

Any problems, let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced a similar issue regarding how to handle dropdown lists using Robot Framework.

See this post: [Select From List selects item but does not commit change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42078974/select-from-list-selects-item-but-does-not-commit-change)

[Akash W.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7149057/akash-w) shared this answer:
Use following keyword.

Pass locator as 1st argument and value as another argument

```
Select from list by label and validate
    [Arguments]    ${locator}      ${select value}
    Focus   ${locator}
    # Select from list by label 
    Select From List By Label   ${locator}  ${select value}
    # Get selected value and validate it against passed value as argument
    ${value} =  Get Selected List Label ${locator}
    Should be equal ${select value} ${value}
```